# Is there a front-end open source for Parse like "http://adminca.com/"?

Tags: parse-platform, serverless-framework, serverless, mbaas, faas

In my company, our team needs an admin panel like adminca. Adminca is slow to connect in our country, so I want to build an "adminca" website using open source for just a few people in our team.

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: have you looked at https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard?

Comment: @ArthurCinader Yes i have. I think i need to add a lot of code to get the effect i want by using parse-dashboard

Comment: @ArthurCinader I want a more functional panel like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=33&v=bBo8nM-DNzc

Comment: @YuliangLi found anything? I'm also searchign a Admin dashboard tool for parse and not like the default admin-dashboard of Parse.